# R: export interactive plots for external users who don't use R

Tags: r, rstudio

As topic, is it possible to export interactive plots from R markdown for other users when the users themselves do not have R installed? If possible, I wouldn't want to publish this on the net as I am dealing with confidential data.

Comment: I'd check into Shiny. I believe it's designed for just this purpose (though I typically see them online, offline might be an option...)

Comment: Also, try the new plotly R package for interactive plots that are JavaScript based. Combination of Shiny + plotly R may be just what you are looking for.